# Firefox session cookie lost after login

Tags: session, firefox, session-cookies

I am working on an application. It has servlets. After I login to application the credentails are set into session attributes, I send another request (call another servlet). The servlet is checking user by 'request.getSession(false)' the session returned is null.
This is the behaviour for firefox v46.
The session is not null if I am opening application in version 52 or chrome v68.Application is working fine.

Is it browser issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the resolution. It seems there's bug in firefox v 46.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1232490#answer-1150525